# Carrierwave Reset after Reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

Both the app and db (mongodb) servers were rebooted last night. All carrierwave mounted uploaders are returning the default images for avatars, even though the files still exist.

I am using fog storage on Rackspace CDN. Each user model contains a field of `avatar_filename`. I tried running `user.avatar.recreate_versions!` however that errors out due to nil.

Is there any way to restore my images (they still exist!) and prevent this from happening again? I have searched around but it doesn't look like this is a common prom.

In my user model:

```
# Avatar
mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
```

AvatarUploader:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :fog

  def default_url
    "/assets/users/profile-default_#{version_name}.png"
  end

  # Large
  version :large do
    resize_to_limit(600, 600)
  end

  # Small
  version :small do
    process :crop
    resize_to_fill(140, 140)
  end

  # Thumbnail
  version :thumb, :from_version => :small do
    resize_to_fill(35, 35)
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
  end

  def filename
    if @filename_created
      @filename_created
    elsif original_filename
      @name ||= Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.dirname(current_path))
      @filename_created = "a_#{timestamp}_#{@name}.#{file.extension}"
      @filename_created
    end
  end

  def timestamp
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_timestamp"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, Time.now.to_i)
  end

  def crop
    if model.crop_x.present?
      resize_to_limit(600, 600)
      manipulate! do |img|
        x = model.crop_x.to_i
        y = model.crop_y.to_i
        w = model.crop_w.to_i
        h = model.crop_h.to_i
        img.crop!(x, y, w, h)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: First things first. Why are you calling mount_uploader on the :avatar field when the model has :avatar_filename field for the avatar storage?
Second - you are defining the filename in the Uploader 2 times - in the default_url and in the filename methods. Can't understand why you need that, and that might be a part of the problem as well.

Comment: @Almaron The ``avatar_filename`` was created by carrierwave/carrierwave_mongoid as a result of mounting the uploader. The default URL is to provide a blank avatar for users who have not uploaded one yet.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the images are there, you could reupload them as remote files with `user.remote_avatar_url = "the url for this avatar"`

To avoid this in the future you have to keep in mind how you are processing the file name. That process is reapplied each time you do `recreate_versions!`. Put this code in your uploader to get around this:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def filename
    if original_filename
      if model && model.read_attribute(:avatar).present?
        model.read_attribute(:avatar)
      else
        # new filename
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can find more information about this in the following wiki article: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files